# Document Html what it is really document in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have code html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body><script src="index.js"></script></body></html>
```

And javascript code in index.js:

```
console.log(document)// HTMLDocument
console.log(document.childNodes[0])//Object DocumentType
```

but when i delete Doctype in html code and i run         `console.log(document.childNodes[0]) i get HTML elements`

What does it all mean? Why document have childNodes?
what it is really document in javascript?

Answer (score 7):

`document.childNodes[0]` is the first element of the page. If there is the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, then this is the first element, thus it returns DocumentType.

If the `DOCTYPE` is not there, then the first element is the `<html>` tag. Thus `document.childNodes[0]` is the elements of the page, because the all the other tags are included in the `html` tag (but nothing is included in the `DOCTYPE` tag)